# Issue with \bar accent and fontspec

Tags: fonts, fontspec, accents, sans-serif

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[png,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{sfmath}
\begin{document}
    $\bar 1$ $\vec 1$ 
\end{document}
```

This produces [image: wrong \bar accent with fontspec and sfmath] in contrast to [image] which is the desired output.

The latter result occurs if the `fontspec` package is removed.

Is there any way to get the math accent right, even if `fontspec` is used (for example to load the Computer Modern Unicode Sans Serif fonts for the main text to complement the sans serif math)?

Comment: Load fontspec `after`  sfmath.

Comment: Well, it works. It there a general rule for this when working with fontspec?

Comment: None that I know.  Just tried to see what happened. Maybe it should be considered a bug, since fontspec is loaded with the nomath option?

Comment: I reported the issue: https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/168. We will see if the fontspec author can tell us more about the problem.

Comment: Perfect! I was unsure on how to do it myself.

Comment: @Bernard Please make that an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should load fontspec `after` sfmath. Incidentally, `\vect` is not extensible and should be replaced, in my opinion, with the `\vv` command from the `esvect` package. In addition, you have eight styles for arrow tips.

```
\documentclass[png,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{sfmath}

\begin{document}

    $\bar 1$ $\vec 1  \vec W \vv{ W} $ 

\end{document}
```

[image]